# golang program terminates after calling linux shell command

Tags: linux, shell, go

I am executing the following golang program (snippet) with root privilege:

```
  binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("auditctl")
  if lookErr != nil {
    panic(lookErr)
  }
  env := os.Environ()

  args :=  []string{"auditctl", "-D"}
  execErr := syscall.Exec(binary, args, env)
  if execErr != nil {
    fmt.Println("error")
    panic(execErr)
  }

  fmt.Println("no error")
```

Because I dont have any auditctl rules in the system, the command print the following in the terminal. This is all normal just like when I type in the shell directly.

```
No rules
```

Except that neither "error" nor "no error" are printed. Which means the golang program terminates right after syscall.Exec. How did this happen and how can I continue execution after syscall.Exec because I have other things to run within the same program.

Comment: Did you try using `os/exec.Cmd` for what you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`syscall.Exec` [invokes `execve(2)`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Exec), which on linux does not return execution to the caller but [replaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) the current (Go) process with the process called.

As David Budworth, and mkopriva suggest.. if you actually want to spawn a separate process and return to your Go code after spawning; consider using [`exec.Command`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Command)

Comment: I am not sure whose answer to take since each person gives half of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @mkopriva mentioned, you probably want exec.Cmd

here's an example:

```
cmd := exec.Command("auditctl", "-D")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Env = os.Environ()
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Println("Failed to run auditctl:",err)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whose answer to take since each person gives half of the answer.